# BigQuery SELECT NULL AS "some_name" : Unexpected String Literal

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to set a string column as NULL in BigQuery with the query

```
SELECT NULL AS "h3-2"
 FROM `sometable` LIMIT 10
```

But I get the error `Syntax error: Unexpected string literal "h3-2" at [1:16]`

How do I set a column as NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed using a string literal.. I added the quotes because h3-2 also wasn't working but instead I had to do

```
SELECT NULL AS h3_2
 FROM `sometable` LIMIT 10
```

to get it to work